# Split View list selection lost in iPad when app goes into background 0

Tags: swiftui

Why am I losing the selected list item on pressing the home button and coming back to the app? This happens only in iPad not in iPhone. Also if I use a NavigationView instead of NavigationSplitView it remembers the state

```
  import SwiftUI
 
struct NavigationSplitViewExample: View {
     private var alphabets = ["A","B","C"]
        @State private var alphabetChosen: String?
 
        var body: some View {
            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all)) {
                List(alphabets, id:\.self,   selection: $alphabetChosen) { alphabets in
                    Text(alphabets)
                }
            } detail: {
                Text(alphabetChosen ?? "0")
                     
            }
        }
}
```

NavigationView works and remembers the state

```
struct ContentView: View {
     private var alphabets = ["A","B","C"]
      @State private var alphabetChosen: String?

   let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 94, maximum: 120)), count: 3)
   
   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List(alphabets, id:\.self) {   alphabet in
               NavigationLink(destination: Text("chosen \(alphabet)")) {
                                  Text(alphabet)
                              }
               }
           }
       .navigationBarTitle(Text("Alphabets"))
       .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
           }
}
```